# Can I transfer my Purchased Nook library to Kindle or other Service?

Tags: kindle, drm, nook

I have a Nook account and library with over 100 purchased titles.  I really would like to take advantage of some of the features of the Kindle Fire but I do not want to give up my current library which I have spend several thousand dollars on.  Is there any way to migrate the books I purchased on Nook to a Kindle or DRM Free account?

Answer (score 3):

Some authors and publishers require their books to be sold DRM free. Those books you can use on other reading platforms. Nook uses the ePub format which is used by just about everyone - Amazon being one of the exceptions. Depending on the specific reader, you might have to convert the file to a supported format. An ebook manager/converter program such as [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) can help you with that.

Beyond that, your options will depend on the type of DRM used. A web search for *Nook DRM* found a document from 2009 describing the Nook DRM as a proprietary form of encryption using a credit card number as the key. Assuming that is correct, then your options will vary depending on where you live. In the US, you do not have any legal options under current law, as the Digital Millennium Copyright Act (DMCA) prohibits the removal of DRM, except under certain special circumstances, such as visually impaired readers wishing to use text-to-speech.